# Is $(1+(1/n))^n$ a binomial? If not, why can we apply the binomial formula on it to approximate e?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

According to my understanding,  $(1+(1/n))^n$ is not a polynomial because there is division by a variable. Thus, $(1+(1/n))^n$ is not a binomial.

In that case, why can we apply the binomial formula on it to approximate e?

Comment: We can apply the binomial formula to $(1 + x)^n$ and plug in $x = 1/n$, if you prefer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fixed numbers $a,b,n$ you have the binomial formula for $(a+b)^n$. Now let $a=1,b=1/n$, voila. Note that you do this computation in each step of your approximation, so $n$ is a *fixed* number.